# Entity Framework 5 Code First - Non-Nullable Foriegn Key Fields

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5, fluent

I am new to Entity Framework and about to embark on a new ASP.NET MVC project using EF5 Code First.

I noticed whilst trying out EF that the Foreign Key fields that are automatically generated for me in my database allow NULL's and I wonder how I configure things in code so as it doesn't allow nulls for these fields?

Example (edited for brevity):

```
public class Shop
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set;

    // Navigation Property.
    Certificate Certificate { get; set; } // ******
}

public class Certificate
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Descrip { get; set; }
}
```

The Navigation Property that I have highlighted automatically generates a field in the Shop table in the DB, called Certificate_Id, but it allows NULL and I'd like to specify that it should not allow NULL's.

How can I do this using the Fluent API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

```
public class TempContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Shop> Shops { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Certificate> Certificates { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Shop>().HasRequired(x => x.Certificate);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `Required` attribute to mark a property as required.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.requiredattribute.aspx)

Here is your example:

```
public class Shop
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set;

    [Required]
    Certificate Certificate { get; set; }
}
```

[Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2010/03/30/data-annotations-in-the-entity-framework-and-code-first.aspx) is an explanation of the different annotations.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class Shop
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    int CertId { get; set; }

    // Navigation Property.
    [ForeignKey("CertId")]
    Certificate Certificate { get; set; } // ******
}

public class Certificate
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Descrip { get; set; }
}
```